# Why does greater-than versus equals make a difference in MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I have a large MyISAM table. It's approaching 1 million rows. It's basically a list of items and some information about them.

There are two indices:

- primary: the item ID
- date (date) and col (int).

I run two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '2011-02-01' AND col < 5 LIMIT 10

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < '2011-02-01' AND col < 5 LIMIT 10
```

The first one finishes in ~0.0005 seconds and the second in ~0.05 seconds. That is 100X difference. Is it wrong for me to expect both of these to run at roughly the same speed? I must not be understanding the indices very well. How can I speed up the second query?

Comment: For both queries, How many records match the first predicate?

Comment: 40,000 for the equals, 55,000 for the less-than, so it's not a major difference

Comment: @bigmac try changing the index format and see what happens.

Comment: @Adam Gent: it has nothing to do with "index format"

Comment: @bigmac: give explains for both queries.

Comment: @zerkms you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regardless of Mysql it boils down to basic algorithm theory.**

Greater than and Less than operations on a large set are slower than Identity operations.
With a large data set an ideal data structure for determining less than or greater is a self balancing tree (binary or n-tree).
On a a self balanced tree the worst case scenario to find all less/greater is **log n**.

The ideal data structure for identity lookup is a hashtable. The performance of hashtables is generally **O(1)** aka fixed time. A hashtable however is not good for greater/less.

Generally a well balanced tree is only slightly less performing than a hashtable (which is how Haskell gets away with using a tree for hashtables).

Thus irregardless of what Mysql does its not surprise that <,> is slower than =

*Old Answer below:*

Because the first one is like Hashtable lookup since its '=' (particularly if your index is a hashtable) it will be faster than the second one which might work better with a tree like index.

Since MySql allows to configure the index format you can try changing that but I'm rather sure the first will always run faster than the second.

Comment: The link to the docs on CREATE INDEX: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Since my table is MyISAM, I can only have a BTREE index. InnoDB is also only BTREE. I am concerned about switching to a less mainstream storage engine as it may involve other caveats I may not be aware of yet.

Comment: This might also help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: @bigmac thats weird I swore I could do HASH with innodb.

Comment: @adam that's what it says on the page that chris posted (there is table a paragraph before the comments start)

Comment: @bigmac your right... The Mysql Workbench tricked me into thinking I could

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have an index on the date column.
The first query uses the index, the second query probably does a linear scan (at least over part of the data). A direct fetch is always faster than a linear scan.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL stores its indexes by default in a BTREE.  No hashing in general.

The short answer for the performance difference is that the < form evaluates more nodes then the = form.

The index that you've got on there (date, col) stores the values roughly like a phone book:

```
2011-01-01, col=1, row_ptr
2011-01-01, col=2, row_ptr
2011-01-01, col=3, row_ptr
etc...
2011-02-01, col=1, row_ptr
2011-02-01, col=2, row_ptr
2011-02-01, col=3, row_ptr
etc...
2011-02-02, col=1, row_ptr
2011-02-02, col=2, row_ptr
etc...
```

...in ascending sorted tree nodes of size B (2011-01-01, col=1) < (2011-01-01, col=2) < (2011-01-02, col=1).

Your question is essentially asking the difference between:

1. *Find all phone numbers with last name 'Smith' and first name starting with 'A'*
2. *Find all phone numbers that come before
       'Smith' and have first name starting with 'A'*.

It should be obvious why #1 is so much faster then #2.

There are also considerations of memory /disk transfer efficiency and heap allocations (= does WAY fewer transfers then <) that account for a not-insignificant amount of time but depend largely on the distribution of the data and the specific location of the 2011-02-01, col=min(col) key record.

- [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree
- [2] http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM
- [3] http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

The first one performs a seek over data where as the second one goes for a scan . Scans are always costlier than seeks hence the time difference .

Its like that, the the scan means running  through all the pages of the book where as seek is directly jumping to a page number.

Hope this might help.